# PHP Code takes only one row from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a little website and i want that it shows every users who have registered in Admin Panel. Problem is that it only shows one user even if 5 people have registered.

PHP:

```
<?php $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC");

while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$steamid = $rows['steamid'];
$tlink = $rows['tlink'];
$email = $rows['email'];
$twitter = $rows['twitter'];
$admin = $rows['admin'];
$name = $rows['name'];
$rank = $rows['rank'];
$avatar = $rows['avatar'];
$ban = $rows['ban'];
}

echo '<img src="'.$avatar.'"> <br> '.$name.' <br> '.$tlink.' ';

?>
```

So how i can make it that it takes every user not only one user?

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Put your `echo` *inside* the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The echo needs to be *inside* the loop:

```
<?php 

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC");

while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $steamid = $rows['steamid'];
    $tlink = $rows['tlink'];
    $email = $rows['email'];
    $twitter = $rows['twitter'];
    $admin = $rows['admin'];
    $name = $rows['name'];
    $rank = $rows['rank'];
    $avatar = $rows['avatar'];
    $ban = $rows['ban'];

    echo '<img src="'.$avatar.'"> <br> '.$name.' <br> '.$tlink.' ';
}

?>
```

---

Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).